# Rendering TopoJSON with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, topojson, react-leaflet

I have been using a GeoJson file for the react-leaflet map, but the file was too big and I got sent a TopoJson file. There is not much information on how to use this with react-leaflet.

This is my code -

`import { Map, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";`

`const topoJson = require("./assets/topo.json");`

```
<Map center={[36.778259, -119.417931]} zoom={4}>
   <TileLayer
     url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
     attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
   />
   <GeoJSON data={topoJson} />
</Map>
```

This is the error when it renders - **Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.**

Any ideas or feedback on how to use a topoJson file whiles using the react-leaflet library, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeoJSON` component from `react-leflet` does not support rendering TopoJSON, the following component could be introduced (which extends `GeoJSON` component and utilizes [`topojson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson)) for that matter:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { GeoJSON, withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import * as topojson from "topojson";

function TopoJSON(props) {
  const layerRef = useRef(null);
  const { data, ...defProps } = props;

  function addData(layer, jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.type === "Topology") {
      for (let key in jsonData.objects) {
        let geojson = topojson.feature(jsonData, jsonData.objects[key]);
        layer.addData(geojson);
      }
    } else {
      layer.addData(jsonData);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const layer = layerRef.current.leafletElement;
    addData(layer, props.data);
  }, []);

  return <GeoJSON ref={layerRef} {...defProps} />;
}

export default withLeaflet(TopoJSON);
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nogiq8)

[Us States TopoJSON file](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/738e320a97af4205c62c9f6455674d10)

**Result**

[image]

**Update** 
There is a dependency to `topojson` package but since nowadays it is deprecated,  [`topojson-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/topojson-client)  is utilized instead.

Comment: thanks for that, I fixed this with topojson-client on the day I posted it, which is very similar to how you have done it above, thanks for your help. I am trying to figure out how to add other features, which I am finding very hard when using react-leaflet instead of the normal leaflet. For example adding a Legend is near impossible...

Comment: @Andrew, good to know. Indeed, it might not be that straightforward to implement custom features for react-leaflet, [this official doc](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html) could be used as a staring point.  P.S. Regarding legend, was also involved recently with visualizing choropleth map and  implementing [this kind of legend](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html) for `react-leaflet`